# ScrollView Page swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `ScrollView` in which there are 10 `viewControllers` I have added each `ViewController` and it contaning two button `Yes` and `No` Button. `Yes` Button take you to the next screen or `ViewController`.
My page is swiping well but whenever i perform an action through `yes` button , i am able to go to the next screen but my page swipe is not working anymore.

1. what i wanted is that if yes button action is performed then swipe of page is done in correct way?

   ```
   @interface PagerViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

   -(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;
   - (void)previousPage;
   - (void)nextPage;
   ```

Comment: make make class method and call this method in view controller you will get swap on button click

Comment: but the way wht you want to achive like this,adding controller to make its width multiple of 10*320

Comment: You should use UIPageViewController you can see here http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: may you list your `-(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;` implement at here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have done inside changePage: but if you have done something like this, then your scrollview page swipe should work fine.

```
- (void)gotoPage
{

    NSInteger page = // page you want to go to;

    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page

    CGRect bounds = self.scrollView.bounds;

    bounds.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(bounds) * page;

    bounds.origin.y = 0;

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:bounds animated:NO];

}
```

You can call above function inside your changePage: method.

Comment: Its not working. I have made custom class for my view controller which is seperate from Scroolview controller class. what i wanted if yes button is clicked the user is able to scroll ? but its not goin to scroll anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I wish It could help you,[See here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/), You should use UIPageViewControleller which has been provided by Apple. [Here Check out Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html). Happy Coding!